# whats the best gem or way for saving images info to database with ruby on rails and saving image to non (cloud server or using aws SDK)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

```
ruby 2.4.2
rails 5.0
gem "paper_clip" , "~> 6.0.0"
```

but my problem is when i upload image it doesnt upload with styles sizes like :blog_article_main , :medium , :thumb and image quality is not uploading with same quality as the image is it comes with very less quality.

here is my model image.rb:

```
belongs_to :vehicle,optional: true
has_attached_file :image,
styles:  {
          :blog_article_main => "940x400#",
          :medium => "300x400#" ,
          :thumb => "200x200"
          },
default_url: "/images/missing.png",
:url  => "/images/:id/:filename"
do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
```

and this is my controller:

```
     # POST /vehicles
  # POST /vehicles.json
  def create
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @vehicle = @user.vehicles.new(vehicle_params)
    @vehicle.proved = 0
    respond_to do |format|
      if @vehicle.save
            # Image.create(vehicle_id: @vehicle.id,image: params[:vehicle]["image_5"])if not params[:vehicle]["image_2"].nil?

        if (params[:vehicle]["image_1"] or params[:vehicle]["image_2"] or params[:vehicle]["image_3"] or params[:vehicle]["image_4"] or params[:vehicle]["image_5"] or params[:vehicle]["image_6"])
          #===== The magic is here ;)
          images = [params[:vehicle]["image_1"] , params[:vehicle]["image_2"] , params[:vehicle]["image_3"] , params[:vehicle]["image_4"] , params[:vehicle]["image_5"] , params[:vehicle]["image_6"]]
          images.each { |image|
            @vehicle.images.create(image: image)if not image.nil?
          }
        end
        session[:category_id] = nil

        format.html { redirect_to @vehicle, notice: 'Vehicle was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @vehicle }
      else
        format.html { render :new}
        format.json { render json: @vehicle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /vehicles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /vehicles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @vehicle = @user.vehicles.new(vehicle_params)
      if @vehicle.update(vehicle_params)

        if params[:vehicle]["image"]
          #===== The magic is here ;)
          @vehicle.images.destroy_all if not @vehicle.images.first.nil?
          params[:vehicle]["image"].each { |image|

            @vehicle.images.create(image: image)
          }
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @vehicle, notice: 'Vehicle was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @vehicle }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @vehicle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /vehicles/1
  # DELETE /vehicles/1.json
  def destroy
    @vehicle.destroy if @vehicle.images.destroy_all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to vehicles_url, notice: 'Vehicle was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  #  def trim_params params

  #   params.each do |x, y|
  #     y.strip! if y.is_a? String
  #   end
  #   params
  # end
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_vehicle
      @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def vehicle_params
      params.require(:vehicle).permit( :categpry_id,attributes.map{|k| k.to_sym })
    end
```

i want to save images without using cloud server i want to save it into my pc
with high quality my project is selling cars and i need to show images in my vehicles show.html.erb and large size